# The DataSource with the JNDI name: weblogic.jdbc.jts.commercePool could not be located

Tags: apache, datasource, jndi, ear, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to deploy `.ear` file on **Weblogic** using **Maven** plugins, and to my suprise i am getting this error; if anyone can help;

```
DataSource with the JNDI name: weblogic.jdbc.jts.commercePool could not be located. Please ensure that the DataSource has been deployed successfully and that the JNDI name in your EJB Deployment descriptor is correct.

 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)




  Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Task 6 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application SchoolPortal [Version=15] on AdminServer.
```

Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer

Comment: Are you trying to deploy a portal application onto a non-portal domain ?

Comment: it is a web-logic portal, and it seem to be failing somehow i don't know. i will appreciate your help

Comment: if you try to deploy a weblogic portal application you need a weblogic portal domain otherwise required librairies and resources will not be available to your application. When you create the domain using the configuration wizzard choose the weblogic portal template.